# Почему в папке Andriod/data не отображается папка с приложением

Tags: android

Создал простое приложение и установил на телефон. Почему в памяти телефона в папке Android/data/не появляется папка с моим приложением? Что нужно сделать чтобы оно там появилось? приложение использует БД простую из одной таблицы. Но при этом все работает, хотя по указанному пути не вижу папки своего приложения

Answer (score 5):

После установки приложение находится в папке `/data/data/app.package.name/`.
Однако это системная папка, и доступ в нее возможен только при наличии рут прав на телефоне.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.